# scrbook chapter numbering

Tags: numbering, chapters, scrbook

I want chapter numbers prefixed by a letter like

```
M1: First chapter of "M" series
M1.1 First section in first chapter of "M" series
M2: Second chapter of "M" series
...
```

then change the prefix, e.g. to R

```
R1: First chapter of "R" series
R2: Second chapter of "R" series
...
```

I tried with some suggestions in scrguide like chapterlinesformat, but either the numbering did not work at all or was not resembled in the toc.

The TOC should look like

```
M1 chapterName1.................1
   M1.1 sectionname.............3
M2 chapterName..................5
R1 chapterName..................8
   R1.1 sectionname............10
```

etc.

Any suggestions are welcome

Sorry for not giving a MWE, since it is NOT working.
one of my attemps follows:
%Minimum NOT working example

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper, 
    10pt,
    pagesize,
    titlepage=true,
    numbers=noenddot,
]{scrbook}
% deutsches Sprachpaket
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\newcommand{\expprefix}{}

\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
        \expprefix\thechapter %\chaptername
        \vspace{6pt}%
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{This is standard numbering}

% set chapter Prefix to M
\renewcommand{\expprefix}{M}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\chapter{This chapter should be numbered M1}
\section{Section1 of first}
\section{Section2 of first}

\chapter{Second chapter of M-series}

%set chapter prefix to R
\renewcommand{\expprefix}{R}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\chapter{This chapter should be numbered R1}
\section{Section1 of first R-chapter}
\section{Section2 of first R-chapter}

\chapter{Second chapter of "R" series}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a suggestion for you: Being a member for more than 2 years should result in a MWE, not only a vague description

Comment: In my opinion you should change `\thechapter` here rather

Comment: How exactly shall I change that?In the "big" LaTeX document every chaper is in its own file, starting with  \chapter{}. My attempt is to leave all the chaper files "as is" and make any changes only to the file where I \input{} the chapters.

Comment: Can you please have look on your other questions. There were some answers to them. Maybe you can accept of them if the have solved your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I have stolen the idea by [Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/) to redefine `\thechapter` and added the formatting of the TOC using the KOMA-Script-specific command `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`. The command `\chapterformat` does not need to be changed in this case.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt, paper=a4, numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\newcommand\expprefix{}
\let\latexorigthechapter\thechapter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\expprefix\latexorigthechapter}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=2.3em]{default}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=3em, indent=2.3em]{default}{section}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{This is standard numbering}

% set chapter Prefix to M
\renewcommand{\expprefix}{M}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\chapter{This chapter should be numbered M1}
\section{Section 1 of first M chapter}
\section{Section 2 of first M chapter}

\chapter{Second chapter of M-series}

% set chapter prefix to R
\renewcommand{\expprefix}{R}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\chapter{This chapter should be numbered R1}
\section{Section 1 of first R chapter}
\section{Section 2 of first R chapter}

\chapter{Second chapter of R series}

\end{document}
```

This is how the TOC looks like:

[image: TOC]

I did not bother to deal with chapter prefixes available in KOMA-Script; they could be added as needed. Furthermore, I removed the document class options that are set by default in order to simplify the MWE.

Comment: I can confirm this. Now the question is how to get the correct TOC.

Comment: @HermannGebhard Please see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the chapter counter is resetted each time when the prefix is changed. So the prefix should be part of the chapter number.

Additionally you have to adjust `tocnumwidth` and `tocindent` for all section levels in TOC.

```
\documentclass[
  10pt,
  numbers=noenddot,
  ngerman
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}

\newcommand*\expprefix{}
\newcommand*\setexpprefix[1]{%
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \def\expprefix{#1}%
}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\expprefix\arabic{chapter}}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocnumwidth=2em
]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=2em,
  tocnumwidth=2.8em
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=4.8em,
  tocnumwidth=4em
]{subsection}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
%\usepackage[naturalnames]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{This is standard numbering}

\setexpprefix{M}% set chapter Prefix to M
\chapter{This chapter should be numbered M1}
\section{Section1 of first}
\section{Section2 of first}
\chapter{Second chapter of M-series}
\blinddocument \Blindtext[2]

\setexpprefix{R}%set chapter prefix to R
\chapter{This chapter should be numbered R1}
\section{Section1 of first R-chapter}
\section{Section2 of first R-chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter of "R" series}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]